# Having trouble getting started with solving differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

This is, I believe, a nonlinear differential equation but if it is linear, I don't really care. What I want is to be able to solve it now.

```
C*V[t]*V'[t] + (C^2)*R*V'[t]^2 - P == 0
```

`C`, `R` and `P` are constants.

`V[t]` is a time-dependent function which I'm trying to solve.

It seems this should be a no brainer for Mathematica and unless I'm doing something wrong (which is quite possible since I just started using this software today), I don't understand why I'm having so much trouble.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Please post the correct solver and corresponding syntax.

This the solver I used:
DSolve[C*V[t]*V'[t] + (C^2)*R*V'[t]^2 - P == 0, V[t], t]

And the answer I got:
{{V[t]->InverseFunction[1/8 (4 Log[#1+Sqrt[4 P R+#1^2]]+(#1 (-#1+Sqrt[4 P R+#1^2]))/(P R))&][-(t/(2 C R))+C[1]]},{V[t]->InverseFunction[1/8 (4 Log[#1+Sqrt[4 P R+#1^2]]+(#1 (#1+Sqrt[4 P R+#1^2]))/(P R))&][t/(2 C R)+C[1]]}}

What are these #?

Comment: What solver did you in your attempt to solve your ODE? Please edit your question so it shows the solver expression you tried

Comment: Since you are a beginner at solving ODEs, you should start by reading this [tutorial material](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithDifferentialEquations.html)

Comment: `InverseFunction[]` means what it says: it represents the inverse of the function given to it, e.g. `InverseFunction[Log]` is the same as `Exp[]`. In your specific case, it is representing the inverse of `f[x_] := 1/8 ((x (-x + Sqrt[4 P R + x^2]))/(P R) + 4 Log[x + Sqrt[4 P R + x^2]])`; the slots (`#`) are standing in for `x`

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for your input. OK so in my specific case, # stands for t (since V[t] is what I'm solving for, correct? What is the number following the # sign? (i.e. #1). How do I get Mathematica to print t instead?

Comment: `#1` specifically stands in (`#`) for the *first* (`1`) argument of the *pure function* within `InverseFunction[]`. (Look up `Slot[]` in the docs for more details.) In your particular case, that function inside is `t` as a function of `V`, which you now invert to get your DE's solution. For your further edification, compare the results of `InverseFunction[Function[x, x^2]]` and `InverseFunction[#1^2 &]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you. I feel I'm going down a rabbit hole... How can I get to the result quickly? I don't know how to obtain the final result from the InverseFunction. Also, I don't know how to treat the "&" symbols. I was expecting a fairly straight forward result since this ODE stems from an electrical circuit. I appreciate your help but I don't really have time to dig into all these esoteric functions.

Comment: "How can I get to the result quickly?" - er... this is the result. Recall that not all transcendental equations have closed form solutions (e.g. try to solve `x == f[x] - Sin[f[x]]` for `f[x]`); this is precisely one situation where your ODE ended up being equivalent to solving a transcendental equation: e.g. solve `(4 Log[V[t] + Sqrt[4 P R + V[t]^2]] + V[t] (Sqrt[4 P R + V[t]^2] - V[t])/(P R))/8 == t/(2 C R) + C[1]` for `V[t]` (and similarly for the other solution).

Comment: @J.M. What I'm thinking is that if I define R, C and P as positive real numbers and with the proper initial conditions, I should obtain a closed answer. It's physics! If you can help me do this, I should readily see the answer I'm expecting.

Comment: This "I should" thinking seduces a lot of people into unproductive rabbit holes, I've found. ;) As you may have seen, even a simple transcendental equation might not have a closed form solution, and this is *Mathematica*'s attempt to tell you that. If physical problems always had closed-form solutions, things like Navier-Stokes would not have been terribly interesting. How about editing your question to include "the answer (you're) expecting"?

Comment: @J.M. Well OK but this is far from being a Navier-Stokes problem. It is a simple capacitor and resistor driven by a constant power source. I know for a fact there is a solution to it.